# Powershell Debug Output

Tags: debugging, powershell

I have a powershell script that creates some DotNetZip ZIP files on a persistent connection on multiple servers, then uses Start-BitsTransfer to move the ZIP files from the remote servers to the local.

I run pretty much the same script on two different servers, on one it barely prints anything to the screen.  On the other, it outputs a LOT - binary looking stuff.  Is this because there is some kind of debug setting that is turned on on the server that is outputting all of this info?  Is there a way I can turn it off?  I'd rather it be more clean like the first server that runs the script.

Thank you!

-Jim

Here is almost the entire script (without my servernames in the $webServers array:

```
Import-Module BitsTransfer

        foreach($i in $webServers) {

                if (!(Test-Path -path \\$i\d$\newDeploy)) {
                    New-Item \\$i\d$\newDeploy -type directory
                }
                if (!(Test-Path -path \\$i\d$\newDeploy\backup)) {
                    New-Item \\$i\d$\newDeploy\backup -type directory
                }   
                if(!(Test-Path \\$i\d$\newDeploy\Ionic.Zip.dll)) {
                    Start-BitsTransfer -Source \\$webDeployServer\d$\newDeploy\Ionic.Zip.dll -Destination \\$i\d$\newDeploy
                }

        }

        foreach($i in $webServers) {

            $sessionForI = New-PSSession -computername $i
            Invoke-Command -Session $sessionForI -ScriptBlock {

                if ((Test-Path D:\\newDeploy\\backup\\OffM.zip)) {
                    Remove-Item D:\\newDeploy\\backup\\OffM.zip
                }
                [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("D:\\newDeploy\\Ionic.Zip.dll");
                $zipfile = new-object Ionic.Zip.ZipFile
                $e = $zipfile.AddSelectedFiles("name != '*.e2e'","D:\inetpub\wwwroot\OffM", "OffM",1)
                $e = $zipfile.AddSelectedFiles("name != '*.e2e'","D:\inetpub\wwwroot\PaEnterprise", "PaEnterprise",1)
                $zipfile.Save("D:\\newDeploy\\backup\\OffM.zip")
                $zipfile.Dispose()

                if ((Test-Path D:\\newDeploy\\backup\\Others.zip)) {
                    Remove-Item D:\\newDeploy\\backup\\Others.zip
                }
                [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("D:\\newDeploy\\Ionic.Zip.dll");
                $zipfile = new-object Ionic.Zip.ZipFile
                $e = $zipfile.AddSelectedFiles("name != '*.e2e'","D:\inetpub\wwwroot\MstrInt-PO", "MstrInt-PO",1)
                $e = $zipfile.AddSelectedFiles("name != '*.e2e'","D:\inetpub\wwwroot\Maint", "Maint",1)
                $zipfile.Save("D:\\newDeploy\\backup\\Others.zip")
                $zipfile.Dispose()

                if ((Test-Path D:\\newDeploy\\backup\\PPO.zip)) {
                    Remove-Item D:\\newDeploy\\backup\\PPO.zip
                }
                [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("D:\\newDeploy\\Ionic.Zip.dll");
                $zipfile = new-object Ionic.Zip.ZipFile
                $e = $zipfile.AddSelectedFiles("name != '*.e2e'","D:\inetpub\wwwroot\HC", "HC",1)
                $e = $zipfile.AddSelectedFiles("name != '*.e2e'","D:\inetpub\wwwroot\PaOn", "PaOn",1)
                if($i -eq 'PYRALNWSP02V') {
                    $e = $zipfile.AddSelectedFiles("name != '*.e2e'","D:\inetpub\wwwroot\HearPl", "HearPl",1)
                } else {
                    $e = $zipfile.AddSelectedFiles("name != '*.e2e'","D:\inetpub\wwwroot\HearPaPlu", "HearPaPlu",1)
                }
                $zipfile.Save("D:\\newDeploy\\backup\\PPO.zip")
                $zipfile.Dispose()

                if ((Test-Path D:\\newDeploy\\backup\\TiMan.zip)) {
                    Remove-Item D:\\newDeploy\\backup\\TiMan.zip
                }
                [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("D:\\newDeploy\\Ionic.Zip.dll");
                $zipfile = new-object Ionic.Zip.ZipFile
                $e = $zipfile.AddSelectedFiles("name != '*.e2e'","D:\inetpub\wwwroot\TiManView", "TiManView",1)
                $e = $zipfile.AddSelectedFiles("name != '*.e2e'","D:\inetpub\wwwroot\TiManOnline", "TiManOnline",1)
                $e = $zipfile.AddSelectedFiles("name != '*.e2e'","D:\inetpub\wwwroot\TiManPOne", "TiManPOne",1)
                $zipfile.Save("D:\\newDeploy\\backup\\TiMan.zip")
                $zipfile.Dispose()

            }
            remove-PSSession -session $sessionForI

        }
        foreach($i in $webServers) {
            if(!(Test-Path -path D:\newDeploy\backup\$i)) {
                New-Item D:\newDeploy\backup\$i -type directory
            }
            Start-BitsTransfer -Source \\$i\d$\newDeploy\backup\OffM.zip -Destination D:\newDeploy\backup\$i
            Start-BitsTransfer -Source \\$i\d$\newDeploy\backup\Others.zip -Destination D:\newDeploy\backup\$i
            Start-BitsTransfer -Source \\$i\d$\newDeploy\backup\PPO.zip -Destination D:\newDeploy\backup\$i
            Start-BitsTransfer -Source \\$i\d$\newDeploy\backup\TiMan.zip -Destination D:\newDeploy\backup\$i
        }
        foreach($i in $webServers) {
            Remove-Item \\$i\d$\newDeploy\backup\OffM.zip
            Remove-Item \\$i\d$\newDeploy\backup\Others.zip
            Remove-Item \\$i\d$\newDeploy\backup\PPO.zip
            Remove-Item \\$i\d$\newDeploy\backup\TiMan.zip
        }
        [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("D:\\newDeploy\\Ionic.Zip.dll");
        $directoryToZip = "D:\newDeploy\backup"
        $date = get-date -format "M-d-yyyy"
        $zipfile = new-object Ionic.Zip.ZipFile
        $e = $zipfile.AddSelectedFiles("name != '*.e2e'",$directoryToZip, "",1)
        $zipfile.Save("D:\\newDeploy\\backup\\"+$date+"_WEBbackup.zip")
        $zipfile.Dispose()
```

Comment: It may help (and definitely won't hurt) to post some of your code.

Comment: There you go!  Thank you for the tip :)

Comment: So which portion of the script is giving you the unwanted output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a debug messages setting like that - `$DebugPreference`

It's default is `SilentlyContinue`. See if it is set to something else.

It would help if you also showed the difference in output. It could also be a verbose output as controlled by the `$VerbosePreference`

Look here to know about the preference varibales - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347731.aspx

Update:

Add a `[void]` before `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom` statements so that the output doesn't pollute the script output.

Comment: I ran [code]dir variable:*preference[/code] and that showed that both servers match on all values, so I guess that's not the issue.  Turns out that pushing the DLL to the remote servers is the issue, after that is done the first time the output doesn't show up again after that... I guess that's okay, but I'm curious still why it does that.  Also, it turns out that it does the same thing on the other server - that one just happened to start with the DLL already on the remote servers..

Comment: the [void] part did it for me.  If it helped user1161625 and you return to SO (hope you do) please mark as accepted answer.

Comment: don't understand what the void did though.. does it just "mute" the output so to speak?

Comment: Sorry, just seeing this.  It's accepted.  Yes, it just mutes the output. :) Thank you.